# Could not update list item in taxonomy field it thrown error like "The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields."

Tags: sharepoint-server, taxonomy

Could not able to update list item in taxonomy field it thrown error 
"The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields"

I tried to increase "List View Lookup Threshold in Central Administration site" but not getting any solution.